# How to add license key in setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am making setup Project for my windows Service.
 while installing, user should enter the license key and i need to verify this. 
but how to set the setup project to prompt for a product key
can anyone help me on this please.

Thanks,

Comment: There are 100s of options out there. Here are just a few:  http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=license%20key&ac=8

Comment: no what i need is how can i set the setup project to prompt for a product key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly you not going to find this in Visual Studio 2012, but you may find it in 2008/2010.

2 Things you looking:

(A) Customer Information User Interface [Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9h65a3%28VS.80%29.aspx)

(B) [SerialNumberTemplate](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xwh311%28VS.80%29.aspx) Property